# How can data structures like Arrays in Java be of any type if they are objects themselves?

Tags: java, oop

I might be getting a bit confused with OOP, just got into it, but if an array in java is an object, where it is calling the Array constructor from the Array class in java to make an instance of it, how is it possible for an Array in Java to be of primitive data type or any object type? Should not the type of the Array be Array type if that is what it is a class of? If I made a class called Car and then made an object called redCar of it, the type of the object is Car still. This does not just apply to Arrays but other data structures as well. Any easy explanations are welcome.

Comment: Because `Object` is the ancestor of all references and the JLS says so. `Object o = new int[3];` And a `Car[]` is **not** a `Car`. See also `System.out.println(new int[0].getClass());`

Answer (score 1):

An array in Java is a special type, just like `String` is.  It is not a primitive type, but you can instantiate it in a special way.  If you make an array of `Car`s, the type is `Car[]`.  An array is what is called a "reference type" in Java.  This means that it does not store anything of its own in memory, it just references other variables in memory.  In the end, any array extends `Object`, just like any other object in Java.  Note that in Java, there is also a class called `Array`.  Arrays in Java are **NOT** instances of `Array`.  `Array` is simply a utility class which provides useful static methods for manipulating and accessing arrays.

Comment: Now I see that there is an Array utility class in Java. So when we make an instance of an Array object, how would we know what class it is coming from since every object does have a class? Also for all the methods the Array utility class all they care about is we that argument being passed in is an Array, they do not care about from what class it is coming from?

Comment: An array doesn't have a class.  Not every object has a class.  An array of `Car`s would have a *type* of `Car[]`, but there is no *class* named `Car[]`.  Every array is, however, an instance of `Object`.  As far as the `Array` utility class goes, all of its methods are `static`.  This means they belong to the class itself, rather than any particular instance of the class.  In fact, there are *no* instances of `Array`, because `Array` cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I agree with everything you have said sir, but this article from GeeksforGeeks, which differs from your point of no class being made for every Array type, mentions how indirectly Java makes a class for every data type for an Array: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-primitive-type-object-java/amp/                                                                                                           Is the article wrong?

Comment: @VividMan That article, as it is currently worded, is wrong. Array types are not classes. That author of the article _could have meant_ that there is a `Class` object for each array type, which is correct, but that's only my speculation. See my answer and the Java Language Specification (JLS) Section 10 for more info.

Comment: No problem!  @Sweeper explains it perfectly.  Arrays are not instances of a class, but they do have a type.  +1 on the comment

Answer (score 1):

> it is calling the Array constructor from the Array class in java to make an instance of it

Incorrect. Array types are not classes. As per [JLS 10.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.8):

> Although an array type is not a class, the `Class` object of every array acts as if...

Therefore, array types don't have constructors. Array objects are created using the `newarray` or `anewarray` bytecode instructions. Note that even though arrays are not instances of a class, they are still *objects*, because as per [JLS 4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1):

> An *object* is a class *instance* or an array.

Just from those two quotes you should realise that Java and the JVM gives arrays very special treatment.

> how is it possible for an Array in Java to be of primitive data type or any object type?

You seem to think there is only one `Array` type. That's not true. You can turn any (non-parameterised) reference type, or a primitive type, into an array type. For example, `Car[]` is type of an array of `Car`s, `int[]` is the type of an array of `int`s. `Car[]` and `int[]` are both different types from `Car` and `int`.

Don't forget that you can add *another* `[]` to an array type to make it a 2D array, such as `Car[][]`, which is also an array type.